# Getting PHP to add multiple XML strings to one document via foreach

Tags: php, arrays, xml, replace, foreach

I'm writing some code which needs to add multiple strings to a XML document. My code currently outputs all the right information but does so on individual files. Currently the code

- loads an xml template
- Locates some specific words in the tempalte
- replaces them with some variables
- outputs a file for each one done

If anybody could help me figure out how I could possibly get all the information put to one file it would be much appreciated - my code is as follows;

```
// Gets the template as PHP string

$filename = 'F:/template.xml';
$contents = file_get_contents($filename); 

*JSON CUSTOMER INFO HERE*

$jsondata = (json_decode($json, true)); 

foreach ($jsondata['results'] as &$data)
{

// Get the value from customer info

$title              = $data['Title'];
$fname              = $data['FirstName'];
$lname              = $data['LastName'];
$road               = $data['Road'];
$town               = $data['Town'];
$county             = $data['County'];
$postcode           = $data['PostCode'];
$customernumber     = $data['CustomerNumber'];
$regionnumber       = $data['RegionNumber'];



// Find these in the template

$find       = array("#Title#",
                    "#FirstName#",
                    "#LastName#",
                    "#Road#",
                    "#Town#",
                    "#County#",
                    "#PostCode#",
                    "#CustomerNumber#",
                    "#RegionNumber#");

// And replace with these

$replace    = array($title,
                    $fname,
                    $lname,
                    $road,
                    $town,
                    $county,
                    $postcode,
                    $customernumber,
                    $regionnumber);

$new        = str_replace($find,
                          $replace,
                          $contents);

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ///////////// Create new XML File /////////////
            //////////////////////////////////////////////

// Create a new XML file for each record of custoemr info 

$handle      = fopen("F:\tempname.xml", "w+");

$filename    = 'F:\tempname.xml';
$filecontent = $new;

// Writees the new PHP string to each XML file

if (is_writable($filename)) 
{ 

    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) 
    {
         print "Cannot open file ($filename)";
         exit;
    }

    // Adds $filecontent to file.

    if (fwrite($handle, $filecontent) === FALSE) 
    {
        print "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
        exit;
    }

    fclose($handle);

} 
else 
{
    print "<b>Error:</b>";
    print "The file $filename is not writable";
    exit();
}


}

?>
```

Comment: Foreach item in the array of customer information,

Comment: It is just a .xml document that holds the values in shown above in the $find array